# Find minimum difference between numbers in array

Tags: code-challenge

STDIN: Array of integers

STDOUT: Smallest difference (the difference between the closest two numbers in the array).

Rules: Given an array of positive integers find the difference between the closest two numbers in the array. Performance should be taken into consideration.

Example:

STDIN: [55, 99, 6, 29, 1, 523, 3]

STDOUT: 2 (e.g. 3-1)

Scoring: Although somewhat informal, the shortest, most efficient (performance wise) will win. Creativity will also be taken into consideration.

Comment: While [tag:fastest-algorithm] questions are allowed, the scoring for this question appears that combined with a subjective metric of "creativity", making this challenge lack an objective winning criterion.

Comment: To close voters: this should not be closed as "needs details or clarity", but instead "does not have an objective winning criteria", as although the spec is bare-bones and could do with some explanation (and updating to modern rules), the main issue is with the missing winning criteria

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I misclicked and used the wrong close reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The R language

**23 characters,  O(n log n)**

```
min(diff(sort(scan())))
```

Example:

```
> min(diff(sort(scan())))
1: 55 99 6
4: 29 1 523 3
8: 
Read 7 items
[1] 2
```

...The `[1] 2` shows the result `2`. (the [1] is to keep track of where in the result vector your are since in R all values are vectors - in this case of length 1)

Comment: well done, although not very creative! :p useful functions though.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 23

```
Min@Differences@Sort@#&
```

Answer (score 2):

#### JavaScript, 127 characters

This is a function that takes the array as a string. It may be O(<sup>(n-1)²</sup>/<sub>2</sub>+<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>-<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>). I have no idea.

```
function(s){s=eval(s);a=Math.abs;m=a(s[i=0]-s[j=1]);for(;i<s.length;j=++i)for(;++j<s.length;)m=(v=a(s[i]-s[j]))<m?v:m;return m}
```

Comment: it's just O(n^2) time complexity

Comment: use sort and you can eliminate the inner loop `s=eval(s).sort;m=a(s[i=0]-s[1]);for(i=2;i<s.length;i++)m=(v=a(s[i]-s[i-1]))<m?v:m;`

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, O(n log n)

### Script that reads from STDIN (113 chars)

```
val s=Console.readLine.split(",").map(_.toInt).sortBy(i=>i)
if(s.size<2)0 else s.tail.zip(s).map(x=>x._1-x._2).min
```

### Function (94 chars)

```
def m(l:Seq[Int])=if(l.size<2)0 else{val s=l.sortBy(i=>i);s.tail.zip(s).map(x=>x._1-x._2).min}
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 28

```
<./&(}.-}:)@/:~&.(".&stdin)_
```

Very straightforward J, drawn down by I/O and parsing.  For those who don't read J fluently:

- `&` and `@` compose verbs
- `<. /` yields a vector's minimum
- `( }. - }: )` performs pairwise substraction
- `/: ~` sorts up
- `&.` performs dark magic so that the next two are used both in the input and output directions
- `".` parses/presents J data
- `stdin` takes care of I/O
- `_` is a dummy argument to `stdin`

Answer (score 2):

## O(n) space and time

### C++ (1644 chars)

Reads from stdin

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int radix(int const& a, int const& r) {return (a >> (r << 3)) & 0xFF;}

template <int R_> 
int radix(int const& a) {return radix(a, R_);}


template <typename It_, typename Cont_>
void distribution(It_ first, It_ const& last, Cont_& d_vector, int const& r) {
        d_vector.resize(256, 0);
        std::fill(d_vector.begin(), d_vector.end(), 0);
        for(; first != last; ++first)
                d_vector[radix(*first, r)]++;
}

template <typename It_, typename Cont_>
void split(It_ first, It_ const& last, Cont_& d_vector, Cont_& slots, int const& r) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<256; cnt += d_vector[i++])
                std::swap(d_vector[i], cnt);

        slots.resize(cnt, 0);
        for(; first != last; ++first)
                slots[d_vector[radix(*first, r)]++] = *first;
}

int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) {
        std::istream_iterator<int> in(std::cin);
        std::istream_iterator<int> end;
        std::vector<int>           numbers;

        /// Read numbers
        std::copy(in, end, std::back_inserter(numbers));

        /// Sanity checks
        if(1 >= numbers.size()) {
                std::cerr << "not enough numbers" << std::endl;
                return -1;
        }

        /// Sort the numbers 4 times using different radix
        std::vector<int> d_vector(256, 0);
        std::vector<int> slots;
        for(int r=0; r<4; ++r) {
                distribution(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), d_vector, r);
                split(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), d_vector, slots, r);
                numbers.swap(slots);
        }

        /// Compute the min difference
        int prev = numbers[1];
        int min  = prev-numbers[0];
        for(std::size_t i=2; i<numbers.size(); ++i) {
                min = std::min(min, numbers[i]-prev);
        }
        std::cout << min << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the radix sort... although, technically, if we're allowed to assume a maximum value for the inputs, I can use the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) to make _any_ of the given solution run in O(1) time and space. (Read up to M inputs, where M is the maximum input value. If there are more inputs, ignore them and output 0; otherwise use the original code, which now runs in bounded time and space since the input length is bounded.)

Comment: I get the impression that radix sort is best able to beat quicksort when there are duplicate values in the input. The interesting thing is that this golf challenge allows us to immediately exit with 0 (zero difference) if there is a duplicate. Hence, I think that populating an `std::set` is a reasonable algorithm. It mightn't be very fast, but it's worst-case performance is reasonable. *Extra:* Don't forget that the number of keys in radix sort will need to be of the order log n anyway (assuming no duplicates in the input), and hence it won't be significantly faster than quicksort. Am I right?

Comment: I like this, although you could have golfed it somewhat. :p

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 16/18 characters

```
x←⎕⋄⌊/2-/(x[⍒x])
```

Or with explicit output:

```
x←⎕⋄⎕←⌊/2-/(x[⍒x])
```

Example:

```
      x←⎕⋄⌊/2-/(x[⍒x])
⎕:
      55 9 6 29 1 523 3
2
```

Explanation:

- First expression:

  - `x←⎕`: Get the input array ( `⎕` ) and assign it ( `←` ) to `x`.
- `⋄`: Expression separator.
- Second expression, right to left:

  - `(x[⍒x])`: Sort the input. `⍒x` returns the set of indices needed to sort `x` in descending order, which is used to index `x` ( `x[...]` ).
  - `2-/`: Splits ( `/` ) the input array into pairs ( `2` ) and finds the difference ( `-` ) between each pair.
  - `⌊/`: Reduce ( `/` ) the array using the floor function ( `⌊` ).

I used [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com) for this.

Comment: you can shorten by two characters `⌊/2-/(x[⍒x←⎕])`

Comment: actually by 4 `⌊/2-/x[⍒x←⎕]`

Answer (score 2):

## K, 15

......

```
{min@1_-':x@<x}
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL 14

(original...21 chars)

```
{⌊/|{(0≠⍵)/⍵},⍵∘.-⍵}⎕
```

(edit new shorter...15 chars)

```
{⌊/|0~⍨,⍵∘.-⍵}⎕
```

(edit again...14 chars)

```
⌊/|0~⍨,y∘.-y←⎕
```

assuming no two numbers are the same

```
⍝ y←⎕     bring in input
⍝ y∘.-y   create subtraction table of array y against array y
⍝ 0~⍨     remove zeros (from same element against itself
⍝                       on diagonal)
⍝ |       absolute value
⍝ ⌊/      reduce with minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

### D (124 chars) O(n log n) time complexity

```
void main(){int[]a;int b;while(readf("%d ",&b))a~=b;b=~0>>>1;sort!(d,c){d-=c;c=d<0?-d:d;b=b<c?b:c;return d;}(a);writeln(b);}
```

using the comparator to keep a running min *while* sorting

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 71 characters, O(n log n)

```
import List;f x=zipWith(-)(tail x)x
main=readLn>>=print.minimum.f.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.6, <strike>56</strike> 48 characters, O(n log n)

New version utilizing `min`, `diff`, and `sort` from numpy.  Inspired by Tommy's answer.

```
from numpy import*
print min(diff(sort(input()))
```

Original version.  Inspired by Zachary Vance's answer.

```
a=sorted(input())
print min(y-x for x,y in zip(a,a[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# 180 Characters**

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(int[]a){Action<int[]> b=Array.Sort;b(a);a=a.Select((c,d)=>(a.Length>d+1?a[d+1]-c:-1)).ToArray();b(a);Console.Write(a[1]);}}
```

Readable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main(int[]a)
    {
        Action<int[]> b = Array.Sort;
        b(a);
        a = a.Select((c, d) => (a.Length > d + 1 ? a[d + 1] - c : -1)).ToArray();
        b(a);
        Console.Write(a[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java

```
public static int minDifference(int[] A) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    if (A.length > 1) {
        int d = Math.abs(A[0] - A[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= A.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 < A.length) {
                int t = Math.abs(A[i] - A[i + 1]);
                if (t < d) d = t;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

-1 is returned when an array is too short

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 39

Sort standard input,subtract each element n from each element n+1, take the absolute value of those differences, and find the minimum of those.

```
Min[Abs[RotateLeft@# - #] &[Sort@Input[]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 49 characters, O(n log n)

```
say+(sort{$a-$b}map$a*1-($a=$_),sort{$b-$a}<>)[1]
```

The input should be on separate lines; the output is printed after input ends.  (I can also make it parse comma-separated input on one line by using the `-naF,` command line switches and replacing `<>` with `@F`.)  The `say` command is available since Perl 5.10.0 with the `-E` switch or with `use 5.010`; per [meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions) its use is allowed at no extra cost.

This uses the same sort-and-diff trick as almost everyone else, with a slight twist to deal with the fact that Perl has no built-in diff command.  It first sorts the input in descending order, substracts each number from the previous one in the list and re-sorts the result in ascending order.  This leaves one negative value (zero minus the largest input) in front of the list, so the code actually outputs the *second* smallest value.  Of course, this only works as long as the input contains at least one positive number, but fortunately the spec says that *all* input values must be positive.

(Also, the latest version plays silly tricks with expression evaluation order to shave off a few more chars: apparently `$a-($a=$_)` always evaluates to 0, but `$a*1-($a=$_)` ends up saving the previous value of `$a` on stack before changing it, avoiding the need to store it in a separate variable.  With Perl, there ain't no such thing as "undefined behavior"... :)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 10 chars

```
<./2-/\\:~
```

It doesn't include explicit input/output, but appending a list to the end like `<./2-/\\:~1,2,3` or `<./2-/\\:~1 2 3` works as one would expect. I'm not too familiar with J's explicit I/O, unfortunately.

Explanatory refactoring:

```
sort_down =: \:~
pair_sub =: 2&(-/\)
min =: <./
min pair_sub sort_down 1 2 3
```

`pair_sub` is slightly altered, since J has some rules for precedence and verb composition that makes `pair_sub =: 2-/\` give an error and `pair_sub =: 2&-/\` give a different output when used in the sentence `min pair_sub sort_down 1 2 3` as compared to `<./2-/\\:~ 1 2 3`.

Comment: I usually use `".1!:1[1` for taking a single line of input.

Answer (score 0):

Java O(n)

```
public int minimumDifference(int[] arr) {
    int minimum = 0;

    if (null != arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        if (length == 1) {
            minimum = arr[0];
        }
        if (length == 2) {
            minimum = Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[1]);
        } else if (length > 2) {
            int minimumSoFar = arr[0];
            int secondMinimumSoFar = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < minimumSoFar) {
                    minimumSoFar = arr[i];
                }
                if (arr[i] > minimumSoFar && arr[i] < secondMinimumSoFar) {
                    secondMinimumSoFar = arr[i];
                }
            }
            minimum = secondMinimumSoFar - minimumSoFar ;
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Python 3.1.3, 77 chars

```
a=sorted(eval(input()))
print(min([abs(x-y)for x,y in zip(a[::2],a[1::2])]))
```

Comment: Can't you replace `abs(x-y)` with `y-x`?

Comment: Looks like this would give an incorrect answer with input of `[1,3,4,6]` because you are striding by 2, which will pair the first with the second items, then the third with the fourth, but does not consider the pair of the second and the third.